# How can I integrate Google and Microsoft authentication with JWT Token in Blazor Webassembly?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Webassembly app (Asp Net Core hosted).

I secured my app using JWT Token. Client makes a request to Server and if the request is valid, server sends JWT Token to client and token is saved in local storage. Client reads the token in storage and this way authentication is handled.

I followed the following practice from Chris Sainty :

https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/

**Now I want to enable users to login app with their Google or Microsoft accounts. What would be the best approach for this?**

I tried Google and Microsoft authentication on server-side but I couldn't pass the token to client. (because there is no request from client..)

Comment: Have you tried follow this case?https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/19

Answer (score 0):

Your response exist in these links:

[Google Authentication by OIDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

[Microsoft Account using MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-microsoft-accounts?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

But the details requires studying related Service and js files.
You can study sources of Remote Authentication Service in Github for both oidc and msal in following sites:
[Web Assembly Authentication Service](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src)
Personally I suggest you to use Microsoft Account which also allow authentication through Google and other providers too. Altough oidc provider is more oidc than msal approach. Microsot implemented Code Authorization flow in msal while Google uses implicit token flow (do not forget that these happen in client side). There is two different js files for implementing the underlying requests so I do not think even the combining them work in this way. May be it is better you code it your self by implementing an authentication state provider which uses JS Interop.
You also can see following example which may help you by DotNet guys:
[Example of Web Assembly](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Components/WebAssembly/testassets)